# Literature about solitons and Hirota derivatives

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, soliton-theory

This summer I'll learn a mini-course about soliton theory ("Soliton equations and symmetric functions" in LHSM (Russian summer school in mathematics).
The web-page of this course is https://mccme.ru/dubna/2019/courses/rozhkovskaya.html
(*warning*: it's in Russian, so here's my translation of its program:

1. Examples of soliton equations, their solutions. Properties of solitons.
2. Definition and properties of Hirota derivatives.
3. KdV and KP equations in terms of Hirota derivatives.
4. Bilinear form of the KP hierarchy.
5. Symmetric functions: main definitions, properties of elementary, complete and power sum symmetric functions.
6. Interpretation of the bilinear form of KP hierarchy in terms of symmetric functions.
7. (If it'll be enough time) Some words about the action of fermions on the symmetric functions and solutions of KP hierarchy).

This program has intrigued me (despite my main interest is representation theory and related topics) and now I'm looking for a book in which the soliton theory will be outlined according to this program (maybe only without symmetric functions...).

I saw Kasman's book but he doesn't say too much about Hirota derivatives and his style seems simplistic to me...

I'll be grateful for anyone who'll give me some references. It'll be great if these books will contain an "algebraic approach" to the subject or some connections with representation theory... But any other reference will also be greeted with admiration!

Comment: crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/335711/11260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really tell if this is what you're looking for, but it's a couple of ideas at least:

- R. Hirota, [The Direct Method in Soliton Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521836603).
- T. Miwa, M. Jimbo, E. Date, [Solitons: Differential Equations, Symmetries and Infinite Dimensional Algebras](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010WETCAW).

Comment: I took a look at the second book... And I think that it's exactly the book I was looking for!
I'm very sorry for not marking your answer as the best.. I think that if I'll mark, somebody who could give me a reference, maybe wouldn't give it, because the best answer'll already be chosen...
Tomorrow I'll mark it, of course.
Thank you very much!

Comment: OK, sounds good. And it's always a good idea not to be too quick to accept answers! :-)